# Are we able to set top-domain cookie in Opera?

Tags: security, cookies, opera

Is there a way in modern Opera (since http://www.opera.com/ru/security/advisory/1047) for "www.xy.ab.com" to read-write cookie for top-domain ".ab.com" ? Or it is officially "bad practice" and now there is no way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

"ab.com" isn't a "top level domain" — it should still work fine. The behaviour change in 12.15 that that advisory is alluding to relates to [public suffixes](http://publicsuffix.org/) — not to any super-domain. The behaviour should match every other web browser except for Opera Desktop < 12.15 (including Opera Mobile, Opera Mini, TVs with Opera…).

Comment: But it doesn't work. Http-response contains header "Set-Cookie: var=1; domain=.ab.com; path=/; HttpOnly" (Network Opera tool shows it) but Storage Opera tool doesn't show this "var=1" at www.xy.ab.com

Comment: It seems that Opera igonores set-cookie for not 'exact' domain